# Disable click on ListView Row with condition

Tags: android, listview

Good morning,
I have a ListView in a first activity (main_activity), when I click on a selected item, I have a new activity (details_activity) that opens with more informations and details, and the user had to check it, then the (details_activity) is closed and back to the main_activity with the same list.
I want to disable the click on listView's rows that are already checked by the user.
I tried to get the position from main_activity to details_activity to use it in SQL to get the informations, it's working.
Then I sent it back, in the main_activity I used this code:

```
mPrr = getSharedPreferences("reponse",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int IDs = mPrr.getInt("ID",-1);
    String rep =mPrr.getString("reponse","");
    if(IDs != -1) {
        lst.getChildAt(IDs).setFocusable(false);
    }
```

Is there any help please?

Comment: Are you able to add boolean flag in your item data(in SQL) ? It will notify that this item is checked by the user or not. In the detail activity, you update this flag depend on action check of the user. When back to main_activity, you only need to refresh the listview, the adapter call getView() method again. Here you can update your logic disable the click

Comment: when the user checks it, he's checking an answer that I insert in a table answer

Answer (score 0):

Write `setClickable(false)` instead of `setFocusable(false);`

Comment: I got this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setClickable(boolean)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Create a ArrayList in adapter than whenever perform click on that row check that row position if position not in list than add position to the array list and perform click else nothing to do.

```
private ArrayList<String> positionClicked = new ArrayList<>();

 public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (!positionClicked.contains(String.valueOf(position))) {
        positionClicked.add(String.valueOf(position));

        //perform Click
    }else {
        //
    }
 }
```

Comment: how can I do it if at the first time I don't have a specific position, the user can get a list of 20 items, he can click on everything he wants, then he can  check or not, if he checks, I want to disable in this case

Answer (score 0):

Create custom `ArrayAdapter`, find the position of item you want to disable click and  `@Overide isEnabled` method

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   if(position == positionYouWannaDisableClick)
      return false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: This one can't work for me, I'm not having a position that I want to disable, it's the user who choose from the list and can select any item at the first time

Comment: Ok, let me think about it again

Comment: Thanks, and it can be helpful, it's like a mail: the user has a list of subjects, he click the email opens in new activity, if he checks, it passes to disabled in the list.

Comment: If user click to the item and it open new activity, it mean we can know the item's position recently clicked. I suppose this position is 0(the first). Now when back to main_activity. I update variable positionYouWannaDisableClick = 0; then call notifyDataSetChanged() to trigger isEnabled() method. You can try this

Comment: Ok I will try it.